# svnadmin: E160004 - root node's predecessor error

Tags: svn, version-control, svnadmin

I just migrated our SVN server from old, version 1.6 to new 1.8.10 SVN...

It did the hotcopy and verified fine from the 1.6.

Now that it's rolled out on the new 1.8.10 SVN server, it can no longer verify, giving this error

```
svnadmin: E160004: r64460's root node's predecessor is r64458 but should be r64459
verify failed, exit code: 1
```

Searching the internet for ages now, it seems that only way to remedy is to do a dump/load cycle.
Even the hotcopy takes hours to do, and it's a 250GB repository. Dumping and loading would be ... dreadful!

Is it possible to dump only the affected ones, like so:

```
svnadmin dump -r 64458:64460 REPO_PATH > DEST_PATH.dump
```

And then load that in again? - Is it necessarily to take the whole repository.

```
svnadmin load -r 64458:64460 REPO_PATH < DEST_PATH.dump
```

So...

1. Anyone with experience or just more knowledge of SVN?
2. I assume this is an error in the repository that has always been there, but is only detected by an update in 1.8.10 (or > 1.6) - Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Details are available at http://stackoverflow.com/q/20431772/737790